# Wrong user agent WP8.1 on IISExpress

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, user-agent, webmatrix, iis-express

I have the following situation:

- I am hosting a local server with Webmatrix 3 (uses internally IISExpress), PHP 5.5
- I opened Webmatrix for serving external (i.e. in LAN) traffic by

  - command prompt `netsh http add urlacl url=http://mycomputername...:8080/ user=\Jeder` (everyone in german)
  - binding localhost to mycomputername in applicationhost.config `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:mycomputername" />`
  - opened incoming requests in my firewall for port 8080
- I have installed Kirby CMS on my local server, which **I can contact** within LAN with a WP8.1 Lumia 1020 and a Nexus 5. When accessing the admin panel **I receive a http 500 error** on IE on Lumia not on Nexus.

I checked user-agents by `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];?>` which results in a correct string for Nexus 5 but not for Lumia. On an external ua-checker Lumia returns correctly `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 8.1; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; tv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; NOKIA; 909) like Gecko"`.

But locally Lumia returns `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0; Trident/3.1; IEMobile/7.0; NOKIA; 909)`.

This is also logged for example in IIS-Logfiles  (IISExpress/Logs/MyWebsite/ex150112.log)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
 2015-01-12 23:28:22 ... POST /panel/login - 8080 - ... Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+Phone+OS+7.0;+Trident/3.1;+IEMobile/7.0;+NOKIA;+909) http://mycomputername:8080/panel/login 500 0 0 93
```

I think that IEMobile may be internally using some compatibility-mode we know from Desktop-IE. But why just for this local site?

Long story short why does IEMobile/WP8.1 send the incorrect user-agent string? Is this because of a strange IISExpress PHP5.5 install, which leads to a false detection? Or does WP8.1 always send false ua to a local Webmatrix site? Or is this a bug in IEMobile?
And how is it possible to change the received ua server-sided to the correct ua?

Comment: No clue if it's a bug or not, but your first string indicates IE11 and the second one indicates that it's running IE7 Compatibility Mode (which is annoying). Maybe you can disable that and get it to work properly?

Comment: How can I disable compatibility mode on windows phone? Or can I server-sided?

Comment: You should answer your own question and flag it as accepted so others who find this know that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/cc817572.aspx)
I simply added a custom http header for disabling wp8 to choose compatibility mode for intranet sites by the following entry in web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EDGE" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```